# Cant select only one face on my mesh

Tags: modeling

I’m trying to select only one face on my mesh, but it’s selecting 2 instead of one. I have cleaned up the loose geometry also merged vertices, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: H Hide that selection, and look behind it, just to be sure? Does it leave the dividing edge behind?

Answer (score 1):

To select faces you need to press 3 to switch to FACE SELECTION mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.

The screen shot shows that the vertices are selected, but it was only the print screen which I did. https://ibb.co/j8bBtRw
When I was trying to select the faces, I had already selected face mode.

Comment: can you make a gif of what actions are you doing to select the face? If you are doing all usual stuff, can you share the blend file? thanks